# ErrorLoadingExtensionAndDefinition error while creating host pool in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-vm-role, wvd

I am not able to create host pool in azure. I am getting the following error:

```
Session ID
2e53a5fd5e54499ab7dc3d6e9b4911d7
Resource ID
Not available
Extension
Microsoft_Azure_WVD
Content
HostpoolBlade
Error code
--
Error reason
ErrorLoadingExtensionAndDefinition
```

I would be grateful if anyone can help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error: `ErrorLoadingExtensionAndDefinition` when I tried creating the Azure Synapse Analytics (workspaces) on Safari browser. I used **Chrome** and it worked just fine. If you're using Edge, please check if it's in the latest version.